# How to render a protected component using a Promise and Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Im using React-Router Version 4.1.2

The only way I can check if a user gets authenticated is via a POST API call because back-end using HTTP Only Cookie.

I have tried to the following to create a protected route, seems it return null at rendering time.

```
    return (
      <Route
        key={path}
        path={path}
        exact={exact}
        render={props => {
          return isAuthenticated().then(resp => {
            return <Component {...props} />
          }).catch(err => {
            window.location = '/user/login'
            return <div />
          })
        }} />
    )
```

Also try async and await approach,

```
    return (
      <Route
        key={path}
        path={path}
        exact={exact}
        render={async props => {
          try {
            const resp = await isAuthenticated()
            return <Component {...props} />
          } catch (e) {
            window.location = '/user/login'
            return <div />
          }
        }} />
    )
```

The error it generated,

```
Route.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. 
You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

What is the correct way to make sure the user is authenticated and then render the protected component OR redirect the user to the login page if he/she is NOT authenticated?

Comment: For whomever down vote the question. leave a reason, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which version of react-router you are using, but I remember there is a method called `onEnter` in version 2.X, I think you can check the auth in these function.

so you code maybe look like this

```
<Router component={yourComponent} onEnter={onEnter}/>

// onEnter function.
 onEnter = (nextState, replace, done) => {
  isAuthenticated().then(res => {done()}).catch(err => {replace('new router')})
}
```

Comment: using 4.1.2 updated the question. `onEnter` is no longer exist in the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

For the async, the error you saw was when you had not logged in. Is that correct? Try this:

```
return (
      <Route
        key={path}
        path={path}
        exact={exact}
        render={async props => {
          try {
            const resp = await isAuthenticated()

            return <Component {...props} />
          } catch (e) {

            return <Redirect to="/user/login" />
          }
        }} />
    )
```

Comment: it also happens when I am logged in.

Comment: and window.location will NOT block return

Comment: Please check your code, 1) the `<Component />` should start with an uppercase. Looks like your code is using a lowercase. 2) if it's still not working, try to return `<div></div>` to test it.

Comment: my code is using `<Component/>` and there is no difference between `<div/>` and  `<div></div>`.

Comment: What I meant was, replacing the `<Component />` with `<div />` to trace the problem. Apart from the authentication function, there is no problem with your code. As for your question, what is the correct way to do an authentication.. usually the authentication is done in `componentDidMount()` of the main App. The state of "logged in" or not is then saved in the state (or redux). This way, you do not have to worry with async call in route.

Comment: Hey Win, I replaced the `<Component/>` to `<div/>` and the issue persists. The main component's `didMount` hook seems like a one-off way to check if the user is authenticated.

Comment: Please do share the solution here. I am curious, to be honest. Because your main route code seems ok.

Comment: I will post the solution later. I try you suggestion and it kind work.

Comment: I will be waiting then. Thanks.